# Как адаптировать dp в Android приложении?

Tags: java, android, xml

Всех приветствую!
Я знаю, что dp - не зависящие от плотности пиксели.
У меня появился вопрос, сколько всего dp в высоте и ширине у телефона?
Эта информация требуется для Android Studio. Хочу с помощью MarginTop высчитать центр. Создавать отдельный LinearLayout - НЕ вариант.

Экраны разные, dp одни. Они не адаптивные, а статические.  От этого возникает ещё один вопрос, связанный с разметкой:

Если экран становится больше либо меньше, то вся разметка слетает. Как адаптировать dp сразу же под все экраны в последней версии Android Studio? Ведь, не зря существуют разделения на low, large и т.д..

По второму вопросу начинает казаться, что первый составлен некорректно.

Помогите, буду ОЧЕНЬ благодарен.

Comment: Количество dp в экране зависит от экрана. Это не проценты, которых всегда 100.

И уж точно их не нужно использовать для вычисления центра экрана.

Comment: Не нужно ничего вычислять, хотите в центр, размещайте в центр без отступов слева и сверху. Используйте правильные контейнеры. Хоть RelativeLayout, хоть ConstraintLayout, хоть два LinearLayout. Разметка должна быть "относительная" и "резиновая".

Answer (score 2):

dp - величина, можно сказать, физическая (как дюймы или сантиметры, только менее точная). Соответственно использовать её следует там, где физический размер имеет критическое значение, например: в слишком мелкую кнопку будет неудобно тыкать, а слишком большая кнопка будет занимать лишнее место без какой-либо пользы.
Для поддержки разных экранов нужно применять сразу несколько техник, в зависимости от назначения вью-элементов и желаемого размещения:

- размеры в dp
- проценты/веса
- привязки к краям/центрам контейнеров и других элементов
- размер на основе содержимого.

Однозначного выбора в пользу того или другого не существует.

Answer (score 0):

У разных телефонов различное количество dp. Как вы указали, dp (Density-independent Pixel) - это не зависящие от плотности пиксели. Поэтому нельзя дать ответ на вопрос, сколько всего dp в высоте и ширине телефона - для разных моделей ответы будут разными. Если только вы не хотите попытаться создать программу, корректно отображающуюся только на одном телефоне, тогда стоит задуматься о гибкости интерфейса.
Гибкость интерфейса можно обеспечить за счёт использования специальных контейнеров компонентов. Они самостоятельно высчитывают точные значения размеров и расположения для графических элементов уже во время выполнения на конкретном устройстве. Вам лишь остаётся задать, каким образом вы хотели бы видеть эти компоненты.
При использовании разных контейнеров можно создавать легко адаптирующиеся к размерам экрана интерфейсы. Не знаю, откуда у вас такая категоричность к [LinearLayout](https://beauty-of-java.site/android-development/linearlayout/), но он подходит для многих задач. Мой самый любимый контейнер - это [ConstraintLayout](https://beauty-of-java.site/android-development/constraintlayout-v-android/). Он основывается на ограничениях (constraints) между компонентами. С его помощью вы легко решите свою задачу и расположите компонент по центру экрана.
Пример кнопки по центру:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Кнопка"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Результат (в отличие от использования marginTop, кнопка останется по центру даже при изменении её высоты):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]